# Android Places API PlaceTypes nonexistent?

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

All I want is a City/Zip autocomplete in Android. I know I can do it manually with a Browser API key and parsing JSON responses, but of course I'd love to save myself the grief and utilize the Android libraries:

[This tutorial](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete) states that you can simply pass in an optional [`AutocompleteFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html), which wants a `Collection<Integer> placeTypes`, which I can only assume comes from [`PlaceTypes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceTypes.html), which OF COURSE only provides "ALL"...

I know there are plenty of [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) to choose from, so is this class/API just not fleshed out yet or what?

I'm using the [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/) in Android Studio 1.1 (using Gradle: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in our documentation. For now you can find the rest of the Place Type constants on the [Place object](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html). Apologies for the inconvenience - we hope to have this fixed in the next Google Play Services release!